# ASP MVC2 deploying to IIS 7 with error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7

after I deployed the application to IIS7 server, it seems fine at the beginning and can display the login page. But after the user inputted the username and password, I have to authenticate the user with the DB connection. At this time, it display error (attached). I guess the error is caused by the reflection during the EntityFramwork load the DB data.

My server has been installed .net framework 3.5 sp1 already.

On the other hand, I have tried another server. If a server has been installed VS2008 and MVC2 package for VS2008, that server can run the application properly in IIS7.

My aim is to run the application on a IIS7 server with .net framework 3.5 only.

Please help me solve this problem.

The error datails:

```
Server Error in '/FDDV_demo' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +111
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCacheEntry.LoadTypesFromAssembly(LoadingContext context) +28
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCacheEntry.InternalLoadAssemblyFromCache(LoadingContext context) +290
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCacheEntry.LoadAssemblyFromCache(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, Dictionary`2 knownAssemblies, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors) +137
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies) +284
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyForType(Type type) +33
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) +80
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateQuery(String queryString, ObjectParameter[] parameters) +106
   FDDV.Models.DBEntities.get_user_master() +113
   FDDV.Controllers.HomeController.validateUser(String userid, String password) +254
   FDDV.Controllers.HomeController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) +134
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +136
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +316
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8682542
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

Comment: Do any answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206848 help?

Comment: John Rasch. I have reinstalled the .net framework 3.5 sp1 but the application also does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. The main cause is the project missed some assembly references. I add the following code to the login function to find out the reflection type load exception. Once again, thanks everyone 's helpful

```
try{
    //Do your work

        } 
    catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            ReflectionTypeLoadException exception = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;

                            if (exception == null)
                                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\TestLog.txt", "Not a ReflectionTypeLoadException ex.");
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (Exception loaderException in exception.LoaderExceptions)
                                {
                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\TestLog.txt", loaderException.Message);
                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\TestLog.txt", loaderException.StackTrace);
                                }
                            }

                            return true;

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faintly recall having a similar issue with MVC 3 when I upgraded a project from MVC 2 and had some version issues in my `web.config`.

Try enabling fusion assembly log binding and see if you can find maybe what the load is failing on.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

I found a script a while back that allowed me to work with fusion log better in IIS (I was having problems where it didn't run in IIS).

Comment: The Assembly Binding Log Viewer shows empty during I open the site in IE. But it shows something when I open SQL server management studio. I have sent you a email for requesting the script. Thanks